# OpenCV `detectMultiScale()` neighbours algorithm

Tags: opencv, face-detection

I have an implemented face detector of my own, but I faced a problem recently that `OpenCV` solves with the `minNeighbors` parameter for `detectMultiScale()` function: I have a lot of false positives. What OpenCV does is leaves only rectangles that have a certain amount of rectangles nearby.
Faces usually have a lot of detections around them.
This is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22249579/opencv-detectmultiscale-minneighbors-parameter).

Intuitively, I understand how it works, but I want to know what algorithm is used under the hood, so that I can implement it myself.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the OpenCV implementation by calling the function `groupRectangles()` and pass your own list of rectangles.

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#grouprectangles

Comment: I need to know how the algorithm works to implement it myself. Or there is a simpler algorithm that I can use.