# what should be the best value of "scaleFactor" to detect face in OpenCV library

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, detection, face-detection, face-recognition

I am using following values to detect face using OpenCv, but result is not  accurate for all images

```
faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
    gray,
    scaleFactor=1.1,
    minNeighbors=5,
    minSize=(30, 30),
    flags = cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
)
```

Comment: the typical face detectors have a training size of 25x25 afair (look at the xml file of your detector). So to increase this by 1 pixel for the first step you would need scale factor of 1.04 . However I dont know whether scaling is n*scale or scale^n for iteration n.

Comment: try by changing `minNeighbours = 3`

Comment: possible duplicates  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22249579/opencv-detectmultiscale-minneighbors-parameter

Answer (score 0):

for higher accuracy, I would use a scaleFactor = 1.05. i.e 5% increment in each iteration

Comment: Welcome to SO! when you reply to a question, just explain a little bit. In your case, you are just exposing to use a different scale factor (1.05 vs 1.10) but, why?