# Optimal Parameters for haarclassifiers

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

I am trying to detect faces and pedestrians using the provided xml files, `haarcascade_frontalface_alt` and `hogcascade_pedestrians.xml`. So far i can get some detection, however the pedestrian detection is pretty poor, and the face detection is average. I am doing it on the iphone with 640x480 or 480x640 images. I can make the images bigger as well however the processing takes faster. Also i might move the processing to a server, however the question remains the same. As of now I am doing this to get the results.

Faces: this first one below doesnt even work. it wont compile.

```
faceDetector.detectMultiScale(matgrey, faces, 1, 1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, cv::Size(30,30));
```

So I've resorted to the function call below.

```
faceDetector.detectMultiScale(matgrey, faces);
```

Pedestrians:

```
hog.detectMultiScale(rgbMat, found, 0, cv::Size(8,8), cv::Size(32,32), 1.05, 2);
```

I really would like to increase the results quality. I was curious if changing the parameters for this would enhance the results. I want optimal results so processing time isn't a huge problem.

Thanks and any feed back would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

For face detection, you cannot set the third parameter (i.e. `scaleFactor` - parameter specifying how much the image size is reduced at each image scale) to be `1`, which you will lose the ability to search the faces in the multi-scale way as it will not be able to be re-sized. Try to change it to `1.05` (i.e. default value) or others.

To get better face detections, check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20805153/2589776) for the recommended values of [`CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html?highlight=detectmultiscale#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale) parameters, .

---

For pedestrian detection, in order to improve its quality, you should try to modify [`HOGDescriptor::detectMultiScale()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.html#gpu-hogdescriptor-detectmultiscale)'s third (i.e. `hit_threshold`) and the last parameters (i.e. `group_threshold`).

Particularly, you should both make them higher in order to get better pedestrian detection result:

- `hit_threshold`: Threshold for the distance between features and SVM classifying plane.
- `group_threshold`: Coefficient to regulate the similarity threshold. When detected, some objects can be covered by many rectangles. The threshold is used in a group of rectangles to retain it.