# OpenCV Face Recognition - Distance from Camera Affects Performance

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition, haar-classifier, cascade-classifier

I am using Python 3.7 and ran a simple face recognition program with **OpenCV** and **Haar cascades**.

I noticed the recognition is much better when I am farther from the camera (one arm length) than when my face takes up most of the screen (6 inches away from camera). Why is it better at recognizing smaller faces?

I read this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-guide-to-face-detection-in-python-3eab0f6b9fc1) on non-face regions and the parameters you can pass in to `faceCascade.detectMultiScale` function.

> In an image, most of the image is a non-face region. Giving equal
>   importance to each region of the image makes no sense, since we should
>   mainly focus on the regions that are most likely to contain a picture.
>   Viola and Jones achieved an increased detection rate while reducing
>   computation time using Cascading Classifiers.
>
> The key idea is to reject sub-windows that do not contain faces while
>   identifying regions that do.

Parameters:

```
scaleFactor : Parameter specifying how much the image size is reduced at each image scale.
minNeighbors : Parameter specifying how many neighbors each candidate rectangle should have to retain it.
minSize : Minimum possible object size. Objects smaller than that are ignored.
maxSize : Maximum possible object size. Objects larger than that are ignored.
```

I referred to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20805153) on the recommended parameter values, which I am already using. Is there anything else I can try to get around this? I want to be able to recognize the face even when I am close to the screen.

Comment: I think that it might be because you get too much detail in the face when it's close to the camera. So, the classifier is focusing on the wrong details and messing up the classifier. You might want to try reducing the resolution of the image, so the detail is dropped. You can use the `resize` function to do that, I believe.

Comment: Thanks @johncederholm that makes sense. I am doing live face recognition on a video stream coming from the webcam. So not sure if continuously resizing is the most performant approach?

Comment: It might save you time with the classifier, as it won't have to analyze as much data. However, I don't know the complexities of the functions.